# Wrap laravel query inside cache::remember

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, caching, laravel-5.8

I want to wrap my laravel query inside the **cache::remember()** method which is not big problem. My problem with it is that my query first calls the function from the controller and there is a file transaction.php in this file. I'm getting this function called and after it, I'm putting some where() conditions on this function return query at the end. The final query gives results, and I'm passing this into the Yajra datatable.
So in short, my query is not on the same file so that i can wrap inside the **cache::remember()** function.

How can I wrap my query, which is placed in two files, controller and transaction.php. I hope you understand.

Here is a function inside the controller:

```
public function index()
{


    $is_admin = $this->businessUtil->is_admin(auth()->user());

    if ( !$is_admin && !auth()->user()->hasAnyPermission(['sell.view', 'sell.create', 'direct_sell.access', 'direct_sell.view', 'view_own_sell_only', 'view_commission_agent_sell', 'access_shipping', 'access_own_shipping', 'access_commission_agent_shipping', 'so.view_all', 'so.view_own']) ) {
        abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
    }

    $business_id = request()->session()->get('user.business_id');
    $is_woocommerce = $this->moduleUtil->isModuleInstalled('Woocommerce');
    $is_tables_enabled = $this->transactionUtil->isModuleEnabled('tables');
    $is_service_staff_enabled = $this->transactionUtil->isModuleEnabled('service_staff');
    $is_types_service_enabled = $this->moduleUtil->isModuleEnabled('types_of_service');

    if (request()->ajax()) {
        $payment_types = $this->transactionUtil->payment_types(null, true, $business_id);
        $with = [];
        $shipping_statuses = $this->transactionUtil->shipping_statuses();

        $sale_type = !empty(request()->input('sale_type')) ? request()->input('sale_type') : 'sell';

        $sells = $this->transactionUtil->getListSells($business_id, $sale_type, request()->customer_id);

        $permitted_locations = auth()->user()->permitted_locations();
        if ($permitted_locations != 'all') {
            $sells->whereIn('transactions.location_id', $permitted_locations);
        }

        //Add condition for created_by,used in sales representative sales report
        if (request()->has('created_by')) {
            $created_by = request()->get('created_by');
            if (!empty($created_by)) {
                $sells->where('transactions.created_by', $created_by);
            }
        }

        $partial_permissions = ['view_own_sell_only', 'view_commission_agent_sell', 'access_own_shipping', 'access_commission_agent_shipping'];
        if (!auth()->user()->can('direct_sell.access')) {
            $sells->where( function($q){
                if (auth()->user()->hasAnyPermission(['view_own_sell_only', 'access_own_shipping'])) {
                    $q->where('transactions.created_by', request()->session()->get('user.id'));
                }

                //if user is commission agent display only assigned sells
                if (auth()->user()->hasAnyPermission(['view_commission_agent_sell', 'access_commission_agent_shipping'])) {
                    $q->orWhere('transactions.commission_agent', request()->session()->get('user.id'));
                }
            });
        }



        if (!empty(request()->input('payment_status')) && request()->input('payment_status') != 'overdue') {
            $sells->where('transactions.payment_status', request()->input('payment_status'));
        } elseif (request()->input('payment_status') == 'overdue') {
            $sells->whereIn('transactions.payment_status', ['due', 'partial'])
                ->whereNotNull('transactions.pay_term_number')
                ->whereNotNull('transactions.pay_term_type')
                ->whereRaw("IF(transactions.pay_term_type='days', DATE_ADD(transactions.transaction_date, INTERVAL transactions.pay_term_number DAY) < CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(transactions.transaction_date, INTERVAL transactions.pay_term_number MONTH) < CURDATE())");
        }

        //Add condition for location,used in sales representative expense report
        if (request()->has('location_id')) {
            $location_id = request()->get('location_id');
            if (!empty($location_id)) {
                $sells->where('transactions.location_id', $location_id);
            }
        }

        if (!empty(request()->input('rewards_only')) && request()->input('rewards_only') == true) {
            $sells->where(function ($q) {
                $q->whereNotNull('transactions.rp_earned')
                ->orWhere('transactions.rp_redeemed', '>', 0);
            });
        }

        if (!empty(request()->customer_id)) {
            $customer_id = request()->customer_id;
            $sells->where('contacts.id', $customer_id);
        }
        if (!empty(request()->start_date) && !empty(request()->end_date)) {
            $start = request()->start_date;
            $end =  request()->end_date;
            $sells->whereDate('transactions.transaction_date', '>=', $start)
                        ->whereDate('transactions.transaction_date', '<=', $end);
        }

        //Check is_direct sell
        if (request()->has('is_direct_sale')) {
            $is_direct_sale = request()->is_direct_sale;
            if ($is_direct_sale == 0) {
                $sells->where('transactions.is_direct_sale', 0);
                $sells->whereNull('transactions.sub_type');
            }
        }

        //Add condition for commission_agent,used in sales representative sales with commission report
        if (request()->has('commission_agent')) {
            $commission_agent = request()->get('commission_agent');
            if (!empty($commission_agent)) {
                $sells->where('transactions.commission_agent', $commission_agent);
            }
        }

        if ($is_woocommerce) {
            $sells->addSelect('transactions.woocommerce_order_id');
            if (request()->only_woocommerce_sells) {
                $sells->whereNotNull('transactions.woocommerce_order_id');
            }
        }

        if (request()->only_subscriptions) {
            $sells->where(function ($q) {
                $q->whereNotNull('transactions.recur_parent_id')
                    ->orWhere('transactions.is_recurring', 1);
            });
        }

        if (!empty(request()->list_for) && request()->list_for == 'service_staff_report') {
            $sells->whereNotNull('transactions.res_waiter_id');
        }

        if (!empty(request()->res_waiter_id)) {
            $sells->where('transactions.res_waiter_id', request()->res_waiter_id);
        }

        if (!empty(request()->input('sub_type'))) {
            $sells->where('transactions.sub_type', request()->input('sub_type'));
        }

        if (!empty(request()->input('created_by'))) {
            $sells->where('transactions.created_by', request()->input('created_by'));
        }

        if (!empty(request()->input('status'))) {
            $sells->where('transactions.status', request()->input('status'));
        }

        if (!empty(request()->input('sales_cmsn_agnt'))) {
            $sells->where('transactions.commission_agent', request()->input('sales_cmsn_agnt'));
        }

        if (!empty(request()->input('service_staffs'))) {
            $sells->where('transactions.res_waiter_id', request()->input('service_staffs'));
        }
        $only_shipments = request()->only_shipments == 'true' ? true : false;
        if ($only_shipments) {
            $sells->whereNotNull('transactions.shipping_status');
        }

        if (!empty(request()->input('shipping_status'))) {
            $sells->where('transactions.shipping_status', request()->input('shipping_status'));
        }

        if (!empty(request()->input('for_dashboard_sales_order'))) {
            $sells->whereIn('transactions.status', ['partial', 'ordered'])
                ->orHavingRaw('so_qty_remaining > 0');
        }

        if ($sale_type == 'sales_order') {
            if (!auth()->user()->can('so.view_all') && auth()->user()->can('so.view_own')) {
                $sells->where('transactions.created_by', request()->session()->get('user.id'));
            }
        }

       if (empty(request()->customer_id)) {
           $sells->groupBy('transactions.id');
       }

        if (!empty(request()->suspended)) {
            $transaction_sub_type = request()->get('transaction_sub_type');
            if (!empty($transaction_sub_type)) {
                $sells->where('transactions.sub_type', $transaction_sub_type);
            } else {
                $sells->where('transactions.sub_type', null);
            }

            $with = ['sell_lines'];

            if ($is_tables_enabled) {
                $with[] = 'table';
            }

            if ($is_service_staff_enabled) {
                $with[] = 'service_staff';
            }

            $sales = $sells->where('transactions.is_suspend', 1)
                        ->with($with)
                        ->addSelect('transactions.is_suspend', 'transactions.res_table_id', 'transactions.res_waiter_id', 'transactions.additional_notes')
                        ->get();

            return view('sale_pos.partials.suspended_sales_modal')->with(compact('sales', 'is_tables_enabled', 'is_service_staff_enabled', 'transaction_sub_type'));
        }

        $with[] = 'payment_lines';
        if (!empty($with)) {
            $sells->with($with);
        }

        //$business_details = $this->businessUtil->getDetails($business_id);
        if ($this->businessUtil->isModuleEnabled('subscription')) {
            $sells->addSelect('transactions.is_recurring', 'transactions.recur_parent_id');
        }
        $sales_order_statuses = Transaction::sales_order_statuses();
        $datatable = Datatables::of($sells)
            ->addColumn(
                'action',
                function ($row) use ($only_shipments, $is_admin, $sale_type) {

                    $html = '<div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle btn-xs" 
                                    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">' .
                                    __("messages.actions") .
                                    '<span class="caret"></span><span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown
                                    </span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" role="menu">' ;

                    if (auth()->user()->can("sell.view") || auth()->user()->can("direct_sell.view") || auth()->user()->can("view_own_sell_only")) {
                        $html .= '<li><a href="#" data-href="' . action("SellController@show", [$row->id]) . '" class="btn-modal" data-container=".view_modal"><i class="fas fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' . __("messages.view") . '</a></li>';
                    }
                    if (!$only_shipments) {
                        if ($row->is_direct_sale == 0) {
                            if (auth()->user()->can("sell.update")) {
                                $html .= '<li><a target="_blank" href="' . action('SellPosController@edit', [$row->id]) . '"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> ' . __("messages.edit") . '</a></li>';
                            }
                        } elseif ($row->type == 'sales_order') {
                            if (auth()->user()->can("so.update")) {
                                $html .= '<li><a target="_blank" href="' . action('SellController@edit', [$row->id]) . '"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> ' . __("messages.edit") . '</a></li>';
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (auth()->user()->can("direct_sell.update")) {
                                $html .= '<li><a target="_blank" href="' . action('SellController@edit', [$row->id]) . '"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> ' . __("messages.edit") . '</a></li>';
                            }
                        }

                        $delete_link = '<li><a href="' . action('SellPosController@destroy', [$row->id]) . '" class="delete-sale"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> ' . __("messages.delete") . '</a></li>';
                        if ($row->is_direct_sale == 0) {
                            if (auth()->user()->can("sell.delete")) {
                                $html .= $delete_link;
                            }
                        } elseif ($row->type == 'sales_order') {
                            if (auth()->user()->can("so.delete")) {
                                $html .= $delete_link;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (auth()->user()->can("direct_sell.delete")) {
                                $html .= $delete_link;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (config('constants.enable_download_pdf') && auth()->user()->can("print_invoice") && $sale_type != 'sales_order') {
                        $html .= '<li><a href="' . route('sell.downloadPdf', [$row->id]) . '" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' . __("lang_v1.download_pdf") . '</a></li>';

                        if (!empty($row->shipping_status)) {
                            $html .= '<li><a href="' . route('packing.downloadPdf', [$row->id]) . '" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' . __("lang_v1.download_paking_pdf") . '</a></li>';
                        }
                    }

                    if (auth()->user()->can("sell.view") || auth()->user()->can("direct_sell.access")) {
                        if (!empty($row->document)) {
                            $document_name = !empty(explode("_", $row->document, 2)[1]) ? explode("_", $row->document, 2)[1] : $row->document ;
                            $html .= '<li><a href="' . url('uploads/documents/' . $row->document) .'" download="' . $document_name . '"><i class="fas fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>' . __("purchase.download_document") . '</a></li>';
                            if (isFileImage($document_name)) {
                                $html .= '<li><a href="#" data-href="' . url('uploads/documents/' . $row->document) .'" class="view_uploaded_document"><i class="fas fa-image" aria-hidden="true"></i>' . __("lang_v1.view_document") . '</a></li>';
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if ($is_admin || auth()->user()->hasAnyPermission(['access_shipping', 'access_own_shipping', 'access_commission_agent_shipping']) ) {
                        $html .= '<li><a href="#" data-href="' . action('SellController@editShipping', [$row->id]) . '" class="btn-modal" data-container=".view_modal"><i class="fas fa-truck" aria-hidden="true"></i>' . __("lang_v1.edit_shipping") . '</a></li>';
                    }

                    if ($row->type == 'sell') {
                        if (auth()->user()->can("print_invoice")) {
                            $html .= '<li><a href="#" class="print-invoice" data-href="' . route('sell.printInvoice', [$row->id]) . '"><i class="fas fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' . __("lang_v1.print_invoice") . '</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="print-invoice" data-href="' . route('sell.printInvoice', [$row->id]) . '?package_slip=true"><i class="fas fa-file-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' . __("lang_v1.packing_slip") . '</a></li>';
                        }
                        $html .= '<li class="divider"></li>';
                        if (!$only_shipments) {
                            if ($row->payment_status != "paid" && auth()->user()->can("sell.payments")) {
                                $html .= '<li><a href="' . action('TransactionPaymentController@addPayment', [$row->id]) . '" class="add_payment_modal"><i class="fas fa-money-bill-alt"></i> ' . __("purchase.add_payment") . '</a></li>';
                            }

                            $html .= '<li><a href="' . action('TransactionPaymentController@show', [$row->id]) . '" class="view_payment_modal"><i class="fas fa-money-bill-alt"></i> ' . __("purchase.view_payments") . '</a></li>';

                            if (auth()->user()->can("sell.create")) {
                                $html .= '<li><a href="' . action('SellController@duplicateSell', [$row->id]) . '"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i> ' . __("lang_v1.duplicate_sell") . '</a></li>

                                <li><a href="' . action('SellReturnController@add', [$row->id]) . '"><i class="fas fa-undo"></i> ' . __("lang_v1.sell_return") . '</a></li>

                                <li><a href="' . action('SellPosController@showInvoiceUrl', [$row->id]) . '" class="view_invoice_url"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> ' . __("lang_v1.view_invoice_url") . '</a></li>';
                            }
                        }

                        $html .= '<li><a href="#" data-href="' . action('NotificationController@getTemplate', ["transaction_id" => $row->id,"template_for" => "new_sale"]) . '" class="btn-modal" data-container=".view_modal"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>' . __("lang_v1.new_sale_notification") . '</a></li>';
                    } else {
                        $html .= '<li><a href="#" data-href="' . action('SellController@viewMedia', ["model_id" => $row->id, "model_type" => "App\Transaction", 'model_media_type' => 'shipping_document']) . '" class="btn-modal" data-container=".view_modal"><i class="fas fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i>' . __("lang_v1.shipping_documents") . '</a></li>';
                    }

                    $html .= '</ul></div>';

                    return $html;
                }
            )
            ->removeColumn('id')
            ->editColumn(
                'final_total',
                '<span class="final-total" data-orig-value="{{$final_total}}">@format_currency($final_total)</span>'
            )
            ->addColumn('products', function($row){
                return $row->product_name;
            })
            ->editColumn(
                'unit_price',
                '<span class="unit-price" data-orig-value="{{$unit_price}}">@format_currency($unit_price)</span>'
            )
            ->editColumn(
                'tax_amount',
                '<span class="total-tax" data-orig-value="{{$tax_amount}}">@format_currency($tax_amount)</span>'
            )
            ->editColumn(
                'total_paid',
                '<span class="total-paid" data-orig-value="{{$total_paid}}">@format_currency($total_paid)</span>'
            )
            ->editColumn(
                'total_before_tax',
                '<span class="total_before_tax" data-orig-value="{{$total_before_tax}}">@format_currency($total_before_tax)</span>'
            )
            ->editColumn(
                'discount_amount',
                function ($row) {
                    $discount = !empty($row->discount_amount) ? $row->discount_amount : 0;

                    if (!empty($discount) && $row->discount_type == 'percentage') {
                        $discount = $row->total_before_tax * ($discount / 100);
                    }

                    return '<span class="total-discount" data-orig-value="' . $discount . '">' . $this->transactionUtil->num_f($discount, true) . '</span>';
                }
            )
            ->editColumn('transaction_date', '{{@format_datetime($transaction_date)}}')
            ->editColumn(
                'payment_status',
                function ($row) {
                    $payment_status = Transaction::getPaymentStatus($row);
                    return (string) view('sell.partials.payment_status', ['payment_status' => $payment_status, 'id' => $row->id]);
                }
            )
            ->editColumn(
                'types_of_service_name',
                '<span class="service-type-label" data-orig-value="{{$types_of_service_name}}" data-status-name="{{$types_of_service_name}}">{{$types_of_service_name}}</span>'
            )
            ->addColumn('total_remaining', function ($row) {
                $total_remaining =  $row->final_total - $row->total_paid;
                $total_remaining_html = '<span class="payment_due" data-orig-value="' . $total_remaining . '">' . $this->transactionUtil->num_f($total_remaining, true) . '</span>';


                return $total_remaining_html;
            })
            ->addColumn('return_due', function ($row) {
                $return_due_html = '';
                if (!empty($row->return_exists)) {
                    $return_due = $row->amount_return - $row->return_paid;
                    $return_due_html .= '<a href="' . action("TransactionPaymentController@show", [$row->return_transaction_id]) . '" class="view_purchase_return_payment_modal"><span class="sell_return_due" data-orig-value="' . $return_due . '">' . $this->transactionUtil->num_f($return_due, true) . '</span></a>';
                }

                return $return_due_html;
            })
            ->editColumn('invoice_no', function ($row) {
                $invoice_no = $row->invoice_no;
                if (!empty($row->woocommerce_order_id)) {
                    $invoice_no .= ' <i class="fab fa-wordpress text-primary no-print" title="' . __('lang_v1.synced_from_woocommerce') . '"></i>';
                }
                if (!empty($row->return_exists)) {
                    $invoice_no .= ' &nbsp;<small class="label bg-red label-round no-print" title="' . __('lang_v1.some_qty_returned_from_sell') .'"><i class="fas fa-undo"></i></small>';
                }
                if (!empty($row->is_recurring)) {
                    $invoice_no .= ' &nbsp;<small class="label bg-red label-round no-print" title="' . __('lang_v1.subscribed_invoice') .'"><i class="fas fa-recycle"></i></small>';
                }

                if (!empty($row->recur_parent_id)) {
                    $invoice_no .= ' &nbsp;<small class="label bg-info label-round no-print" title="' . __('lang_v1.subscription_invoice') .'"><i class="fas fa-recycle"></i></small>';
                }

                if (!empty($row->is_export)) {
                    $invoice_no .= '</br><small class="label label-default no-print" title="' . __('lang_v1.export') .'">'.__('lang_v1.export').'</small>';
                }

                return $invoice_no;
            })
            ->editColumn('shipping_status', function ($row) use ($shipping_statuses) {
                $status_color = !empty($this->shipping_status_colors[$row->shipping_status]) ? $this->shipping_status_colors[$row->shipping_status] : 'bg-gray';
                $status = !empty($row->shipping_status) ? '<a href="#" class="btn-modal" data-href="' . action('SellController@editShipping', [$row->id]) . '" data-container=".view_modal"><span class="label ' . $status_color .'">' . $shipping_statuses[$row->shipping_status] . '</span></a>' : '';

                return $status;
            })
            ->addColumn('conatct_name', '@if(!empty($supplier_business_name)) {{$supplier_business_name}}, <br> @endif {{$name}}')
            ->editColumn('quantity', '{{@format_quantity($quantity)}}')
            ->filterColumn('conatct_name', function ($query, $keyword) {
                $query->where( function($q) use($keyword) {
                    $q->where('contacts.name', 'like', "%{$keyword}%")
                    ->orWhere('contacts.supplier_business_name', 'like', "%{$keyword}%");
                });
            })
            ->addColumn('payment_methods', function ($row) use ($payment_types) {
                $methods = array_unique($row->payment_lines->pluck('method')->toArray());
                $count = count($methods);
                $payment_method = '';
                if ($count == 1) {
                    $payment_method = $payment_types[$methods[0]];
                } elseif ($count > 1) {
                    $payment_method = __('lang_v1.checkout_multi_pay');
                }

                $html = !empty($payment_method) ? '<span class="payment-method" data-orig-value="' . $payment_method . '" data-status-name="' . $payment_method . '">' . $payment_method . '</span>' : '';

                return $html;
            })
            ->editColumn('status', function($row) use($sales_order_statuses, $is_admin){
                $status = '';

                if ($row->type == 'sales_order') {
                    if ($is_admin && $row->status != 'completed') {
                        $status = '<span class="edit-so-status label ' . $sales_order_statuses[$row->status]['class'] . '" data-href="'.action("SalesOrderController@getEditSalesOrderStatus", ['id' => $row->id]).'">' . $sales_order_statuses[$row->status]['label'] . '</span>';
                    } else {
                        $status = '<span class="label ' . $sales_order_statuses[$row->status]['class'] . '" >' . $sales_order_statuses[$row->status]['label'] . '</span>';
                    }
                }

                return $status;
            })
            ->editColumn('so_qty_remaining', '{{@format_quantity($so_qty_remaining)}}')
            ->setRowAttr([
                'data-href' => function ($row) {
                    if (auth()->user()->can("sell.view") || auth()->user()->can("view_own_sell_only")) {
                        return  action('SellController@show', [$row->id]) ;
                    } else {
                        return '';
                    }
                }]);

        $rawColumns = ['final_total', 'unit_price', 'action', 'total_paid', 'total_remaining', 'payment_status', 'invoice_no', 'discount_amount', 'tax_amount', 'total_before_tax', 'shipping_status', 'types_of_service_name', 'payment_methods', 'return_due', 'conatct_name', 'status'];

        return $datatable->rawColumns($rawColumns)
                  ->make(true);
    }

    $business_locations = BusinessLocation::forDropdown($business_id, false);
    $customers = Contact::customersDropdown($business_id, false);
    $sales_representative = User::forDropdown($business_id, false, false, true);

    //Commission agent filter
    $is_cmsn_agent_enabled = request()->session()->get('business.sales_cmsn_agnt');
    $commission_agents = [];
    if (!empty($is_cmsn_agent_enabled)) {
        $commission_agents = User::forDropdown($business_id, false, true, true);
    }

    //Service staff filter
    $service_staffs = null;
    if ($this->productUtil->isModuleEnabled('service_staff')) {
        $service_staffs = $this->productUtil->serviceStaffDropdown($business_id);
    }

    $shipping_statuses = $this->transactionUtil->shipping_statuses();

    return view('sell.index')
    ->with(compact('business_locations', 'customers', 'is_woocommerce', 'sales_representative', 'is_cmsn_agent_enabled', 'commission_agents', 'service_staffs', 'is_tables_enabled', 'is_service_staff_enabled', 'is_types_service_enabled', 'shipping_statuses'));
}
```

You can see attached images My aim is how i can use **cache::remember** on this query.

[Controller file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLM4L.png)

[transactions.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0d9M.png)

Comment: You should share the relevant code in the question itself, not as images. It's very hard to follow when people have to jump around in various pages. I personally am not very eager to have imgur collect any of my personal information so I can see what your issue is.

Comment: i have added the code.

Comment: That is way too much code. Try and create a [mre] and more briefly explain your problem.

Comment: Ok sir let me do this.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the transactionUtil file to do the entire query. You also need to gather all parts that are used to construct the query to form a unique key for a unique combination of them. For example this could be a function in the transaction util:

```
function getFullResult($business_id, $sale_type) {
        $queryParameters = array_merge(compact('business_id, sale_type'), request()->all()); // You can filter these into the ones that are used for the query only
        $cacheDurationSeconds = 3600;
        return Cache::remember('getFullResult'.md5(json_encode($queryParameters)), $cacheDurationSeconds, function () use ($business_id, $sale_type) {      
             $sells = $this->getListSells($business_id, $sale_type, request()->customer_id);
            if (request()->only_subscriptions) {
                $sells->where(function ($q) {
                    $q->whereNotNull('transactions.recur_parent_id')
                    ->orWhere('transactions.is_recurring', 1);
                 });
            }

            if (!empty(request()->list_for) && request()->list_for == 'service_staff_report') {
                $sells->whereNotNull('transactions.res_waiter_id');
            }
            // ....
             return $sells->where('transactions.is_suspend', 1)
                        ->with($with)
                        ->addSelect('transactions.is_suspend', 'transactions.res_table_id', 'transactions.res_waiter_id', 'transactions.additional_notes')
                        ->get();   
       });

}
```

Here I used `md5` to generate the unique key since its fast and has an acceptably low likelyhood of hash collisions for this particular use case.

However given the complexity of the query you need to question the likelihood you get multiple of the same parameters in a request because if you won't then caching can't help.

Comment: So you mean i need to wrap my all remaining code including getListSell() inside the cache ?

Comment: All the code that is needed to construct and execute the query must go in the `remember` callback so it's only ever executed if that exact query has not been cached before

Comment: Wao, thank you so much Every thing is clear about which i was confused.